# Xamarin Forms Labs Geolocation sample

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I downloaded the source for Xamarin Forms Labs, and was trying to run the geolocator sample for the android project. When you click the Get Position button, the location message returned is "Cancelled". I tried making a new xamarin forms project in VS by following these steps: file > new project > Xamarin PCL. When I install xamarin forms labs in that project and use it, I get the same message.  I can, however, get the Windows Phone example to work.  I'm not sure if maybe the Android emulator that installs with Xamarin can even connect to the network on my machine or not.  That would explain why it cant get the location

Comment: The android app have the ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION permission?

Comment: Thank you, yes I have this set in the manifest                            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

Comment: Hi Patrick, for the sake of future Users/Viewers, if the answer below solves your issue, please mark it as the solution.

Answer (score 6):

*(This is a little late, but just submitting in case anyone finds this via a search)*

Double check your platform permissions.

**For Android:**
You must request the following permissions within your Android Project

1. `ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION`
2. `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION`

**For iOS:**
In iOS 8 you now have to call either `RequestWhenInUseAuthorization` or `RequestAlwaysAuthorization` on the location manager.

Additionally you need to add either the concisely named `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription` or `NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription` to your `Info.plist`.

**For Windows Phone:**
You must set the `ID_CAP_LOCATION` permission.

**Xamarin Forms**
If you are developing a Xamarin Forms app, you could try using the Geolocator (Xamarin.Plugin) sample, just remember to add your permissions :)

Sample:

```
var locator = CrossGeolocator.Current;
locator.DesiredAccuracy = 50;

var position = await locator.GetPositionAsync (timeout: 10000);

Console.WriteLine ("Position Status: {0}", position.Timestamp);
Console.WriteLine ("Position Latitude: {0}", position.Latitude);
Console.WriteLine ("Position Longitude: {0}", position.Longitude);
```

Comment: More info about the Geolocator sample (and some other Xamarin.Plugins), check out https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/Xamarin.Plugins